# Get image from Google API Chart

Tags: c#, google-visualization

I have a C# code running on server and I need to generate some charts using Google API Chart and then save those to images on server.

I remember Google API Chart had a wizard where you can create the chart but now it's 100% JavaScript so don't know if there is a way to do it.

Is that possible?

Comment: once the chart is created you can use `chart.getImageURI()` to get a PNG -- see [reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) -- basically returns a base 64 string you can save as .png or inclide in `src` tag, etc...

Comment: So you recommend me to first create the image using the HTML and Javascript tooling. Then get the image URL and use that right? Is the getImageURI() static? or it can change later?

Comment: Does [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) help you some?

Comment: @WhiteHat Appreciate if you can share with me working examples, then I use that as the right answer becuase it sounds the right way. Appreciate so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the `'ready'` has fired on the `chart`,
you can use `getImageURI` to get a base 64 string,
which can be saved as .PNG,
or included in an `img` tag,
as in the following example...

to use a [frozen version](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes), you can replace `'current'` with the latest save -- `'45'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', '2005');
    data.addColumn('number', '2006');
    data.addRows([
       [new Date('01/01/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/02/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/03/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/04/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/05/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/06/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/07/2016'), 196, 207]
    ]);
    var options = {
      height: 400
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      document.getElementById('image_div').innerHTML = '<img alt="Chart" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Chart</div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div>Image</div>
<div id="image_div"></div>
```

Comment: What do you think about this, having the html that generates the chart, then a C# make a web request to that page and get the image from the response? That way It doesnt matter if the chartImageURI changes later because I will get always the one that is being rendered.

Comment: right, that works. but earlier, I wasn't sure what you meant by the URI changing. it's not an address to anywhere -- it's a string (base 64) representation of the chart -- like taking a PNG file and saving it as a string

Comment: Ohhh its a base 64 amazing... that will never change then. Appreciat so much

Comment: Didn't work because its not possible to get an image from C# that is being rendered with Javascript ajax call.

Comment: not much experience with C#, but surely there is a way, could you post the code being called from ajax? what if you have a page that draws a chart, then when the chart's `'ready'` event fires, sends the image uri back to c# via ajax? idk, thinking out loud here...

Comment: Exactly I ended doing that... using jquery ajax and send back to server the base64 image and save to server, then I can take it.... Yes thats the way!!!

Comment: cheers! also, i've seen sizing issues if the chart being drawn isn't actually visible. to avoid, set specific sizes on the `chart` and `chartArea` in the config options...

Answer (score 0):

The static chart API has been deprecated and the wizard offline for a while: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard

But the API still works and the gallery docs can get you going:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/chart_gall