# Sending reporting mail with chart

Tags: php, email, charts

the question I am asking is from a code-architecture point of view. I am preparing a report in php which is built with a string `$message` and then send via a php `mail` function.

For example the report is built in the php file like that(basically concatenates strings):

```
$message .= <<<HTML
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
HTML;
```

Further, I would like to include a chart. However, trying the following example and sending it per mail I get no chart and an empty `<div style="width:900px;min-height:500px"></div> ==$0` value.

```
$message.=<<<HTML
        <tr valign="top" align="center">
              <script type="text/javascript">
                google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {

                  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
                    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
                    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
                    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
                    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
                  ]);

                  var options = {
                    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
                    bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
                    legend: 'none',
                  };

                  var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
                  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

                  // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.
                  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
                    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
                  });

                  chart.draw(data, options);

              }
              </script>
              <div id='chart_div'></div>
        </tr>
HTML;
```

My guess is that javascript is not accepted by f.ex. GMail. Hence, I am trying to create a png beforehand which is then included in the report.

My preferred way of doing this would be the [google charts library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example), however, it has no support for php and is entirely based on JavaScript.

Hence, my questions are:

1. How can I use the google chart library in my code?
2. Any other suggestions if above does not work?

I appreciate if you could provide an example!

Thx in advance!

Comment: You can use a something like http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ to capture a screenshot as a png.

Comment: Have a look at this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: @rjdown Thx for your answer! Any suggestions how to execute the javascript within php?

Comment: i would recommend having a page that draws the chart, then when the `'ready'` event fires, sends the image string (`getImageURI`) via ajax to another php, which then sends the email...

Comment: @WhiteHat Can you provide a working example? I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464203/5090771) is a working example of getting the chart's image when the `'ready'` event fires -- although it appears from the question, you're good there -- [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/5090771) is an excellent example of using jquery / ajax to post data back to php, including a php snippet to receive the data -- add the `$.ajax` call, with the image string as the data, to the `'ready'` event function -- there are too many pieces to construct a complete working example, not sure of a _fiddle_ that allows post back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Email clients strip Javascript, SVG, and other formats, so you can't use a chart library directly in email.

Your options include:

- Use [getImageURI](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) to generate a PNG of your chart and send it to your server to be emailed.  This is probably the best solution if you know a client will load every chart before it needs to be emailed.
- Use a tool like [wkhtmltoimage](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to "headlessly" render a webpage that displays your charts and save it as an image.
- Use a chart image rendering web service like [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io/) to generate the chart image (fyi: this is an open-source project that I started).

QuickChart in particular is built on [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), so you'd have to create a Chart.js chart definition as a string:

```php
$chartConfig = "{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Copper', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45],
      backgroundColor: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
    },
    legend: {
      display: false    
    }
  }
}";
```

I've used a static string to match your example, but you can include dynamic variables like in any other PHP string.

Then encode this string into a URL:

```php
$chartUrl = 'https://quickchart.io/chart?c=' . urlencode($chartConfig);
```

This URL returns a chart that looks like this:
[image: Chart.js chart rendered in PHP]

Finally, add the chart to your email body as an HTML image tag:

```php
$message .= "<img src=\"$chartUrl\"/>";
```

Comment: I have tried this same example.But in the mail body I am only getting a box with a red cross. Can you help?

Comment: @veganbuchat Can you share your full image URL?  You should make sure your chart config is URL encoded.

Comment: I was successfully implemented the code. but now I need to get mysql data instead of dummy data?what changes to be done. I made a question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842364/how-to-get-mysql-data-and-generate-charts-and-attach-in-email-body