# How to get mysql data and generate charts and attach in email body?

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays

Basically I need to automate a email with a chart which have sql data. After some research here I have found Send mail with chart this and it works fine. Here is the basic code which I reffered.

```
$configdata = '{
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "data": [91, 12] 
      } 
    ],
    "labels": ["Data1", "Data2"] 
  } 
}';
```

I need to replace these data and labels with my sql query results. So I am planning to perform following method to get this.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query2 = "select day,value from test01 order by day_value asc;";

$jsonArray = array();

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  //Converting the results into an associative array
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $jsonArrayItem = array();
    $jsonArrayItem['label'] = $row['day'];
    $jsonArrayItem['value'] = $row['value '];
    //append the above created object into the main array.
    array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
  }

     $chartConfig = '{
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "data": [//need to implement value array] 
      } 
    ],
    "labels": [//need to implement label array] 
  } 
}';

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Now I need to implement value and label arrays to above position so I can retrieve the chart. Can anyone show me how to continue this code? or any other easier way to implement what I need?

Finally I need to get,

```
$data = '{
      "type": "line",
      "data": {
        "datasets": [
          {
            "data": [525.65,568.95,859.65] 
          } 
        ],
        "labels": ["2022-01-25","2022-01-24","2022-01-23"] 
      } 
    }';
  
    }
```

Comment: What chart generator are you using? (or planning to use ? )

Comment: @KenLee after getting $data, i am going to encode it and going to use quickchart.io

Comment: Hint: save the `quickchart.io` generated chart into image (png format) and then send it as attachment in email.

Comment: DO NOT try and assemble JSON manually, in text form. Create & populate the appropriate PHP data structure, and then use `json_encode` on it afterwards.