# Google Charts: Is it possible to have a pie chart substituting the dot in the scatterplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm building an interactive widget using Google Charts.

For now, got a pie chart and a scatterplot as you can see bellow.

[image: like this]

Although, **would like to have in the scatterplot a pie chart instead of the blue tiny dot** (can even be an image.

Any idea in how to do this?

Spend 4 hours doing research and didn't find anything that would let me do it.

Comment: I'm far from knowing anything of finance, but looks like they don't have any categories in common...?

Comment: they indeed don't but the dot could be substituted by and image, maybe?

Comment: The [points](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) on the scatter chart can be modified in size and shape like squares, and stars.

Comment: ok that's what I thought.

Is there any other option that enables one to do scatter pie plots with JS?

Comment: _sounds_ possible, you could use the `getImageURI` method to get an image of the pie chart, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38464203/5090771) -- then overlay the _blue tiny dot_ with the image, using the `getChartLayoutInterface` method, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debug?

***SCRIPT***

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

////Callback that draws the scatter

        function draw0RiskChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Risk in %', 'Return in %'],
      [ 9.87,      6.53]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Risk vs. Return with 0% Hedge Fund',
      hAxis: {title: 'Risk', minValue: 5, maxValue: 10},
      vAxis: {title: 'Return', minValue: 5, maxValue: 10},
      width:400,
      height:300
    };

    var container = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('0risk_chart_div'));
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);


    // Wait for the chart to finish drawing before calling the getImageURI() method.

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();

            container.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

            // add image above in every element

                var xPos = layout.getXLocation(data.getValue(i, 0));
                var yPos = layout.getYLocation(data.getValue(i, 1));

                var whiteHat = container.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
                whiteHat.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/16/clone_old.png';
                whiteHat.className = 'whiteHat';

                // 16x16 (image size in this example)
                whiteHat.style.top = (yPos - 16) + 'px';
                whiteHat.style.left = (xPos) + 'px';

            }

            console.log(container.innerHTML);
        });



    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

***STYLE***

```
.whiteHat {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

***BODY***

```
<div id="0risk_chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Remove `if (i === 0) {  }` out of for loop, that will only allow you one img and stop.

Comment: Removing it won't fix it but having it will keep it broken.

Comment: Any suggestions in how to fix it?

Comment: error on line 22. The container is supposed to be the div element not an instance of the graph itself. 

var container = document.getElementById('0risk_chart_div');
var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);

Comment: Yeah so basically: `var container = document.getElementById('0risk_chart_div'); ` `var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);` works.