# Show the X-axis title in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, android, google-visualization, column-chart

I want to show the x-axis heading of a column chart using `google charts` in Android web view.
I am trying to show the x-axis heading as `Year` in

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);
```

But it is not showing heading. 
Complete Code;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

     function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
    },
    height: 600,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Company Performance'
  };

       var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i *think* the option you're looking for is --> `hAxis.title`

```
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year'
    },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
  ]);

  var options = {
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
    },
    height: 600,
    hAxis: {
      title: data.getColumnLabel(0)
    },
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Company Performance'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Superb. But what is the reason for not showing heading defined at ` ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],`?

Comment: those are the headings for the columns in the data -- you can use those with --> `data.getColumnLabel(0)` -- see changed answer above...

Comment: can we generate images with this rendered chart?

Comment: you can use the `getImageURI` method `chart.getImageURI()` --> [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38464203/5090771)...