# how to take a screenshot of piece of a webpage with phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, headless

I understand how to take screenshot of entire webpage but how about capturing the view of an specific element using phantomjs.
I'm trying as follow

```js
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
page.content = page.open('https://www.google.co.in/');
page.evaluate(function() {
  
   
var canvas = document.getElementById('hplogo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
var imgdata =  document.querySelectorAll('img');
img.src = imgdata[0].src;

  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);



}); 
page.render('canvas.png'); 
phantom.exit();
```

Above code is not working, What 'm doing in above code is selecting the element of Google webpage img section though id then create an object of image and assign the src of query selected tag IMG and then fill the pattern, my hours of hard work did not yield any result.

WHAT I WANT: I want the screenshot of an img element rendered through 'page.open' which can be selected by query selector and output the png file. OTHER ALTERNATIVES OF PHANTOMJS ARE WELCOME.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is phantomjs a hard requirement? If not, have a look at Chrome headless and one of the many libraries to interact with it. Puppeteer arguably being the most popular. Here’s a Q&A doing something very similar to what you want using puppeteer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532808/render-google-charts-with-puppeteer

Comment: https://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html